# How to set a cookie that prevents further javascript alerts?

Tags: javascript, cookies, alert

I have this code for detecting android:

```
var mobile = (/android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile){
    alert("Message to android users");
}
```

...but how do I get that script to also set a cookie so the android user doesn't continue getting the alert (either on reloading the page, returning later to the page, or navigating to other pages which have the alert)?

I also have this, which uses a cookie to avoid a user viewing a "welcome page" they've already seen:

```
var RedirectURL = "http://www.example.com/real-home-page.html";
var DaysToLive = "365";
var CookieName = "FirstVisit";
function Action() {
location.href = RedirectURL;
}
DaysToLive = parseInt(DaysToLive);
var Value = 'bypass page next time';
function GetCookie() {
var cookiecontent = '';
if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
   var cookiename = CookieName + '=';
   var cookiebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(cookiename);
   var cookieend = 0;
   if(cookiebegin > -1) {
      cookiebegin += cookiename.length;
      cookieend = document.cookie.indexOf(";",cookiebegin);
      if(cookieend < cookiebegin) { cookieend = document.cookie.length; }
      cookiecontent = document.cookie.substring(cookiebegin,cookieend);
      }
   }
if(cookiecontent.length > 0) { return true; }
return false;
}
function SetCookie() {
var exp = '';
if(DaysToLive > 0) {
   var now = new Date();
   then = now.getTime() + (DaysToLive * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   now.setTime(then);
   exp = '; expires=' + now.toGMTString();
   }
document.cookie = CookieName + '=' + Value + exp;
return true;
}
if(GetCookie() == true) { Action(); }
SetCookie();
```

Can the second script be adapted and combined into the first to do something like:

```
function Action() {
don't-open-that-alert-again;
```

I've googled and found some js cookie scripts, but all over 100K. Prefer something as succinct as the above.

Comment: So set a different cookie value. My honest opinion, use localstorage, not cookie since it appears that the server does not need it.

Comment: I'm a novice, and have no clue about what cookie value to set. I got both scripts off the web, but can't find one that sets a cookie along with a javascript alert.

Comment: To solve the problem, I adapted an EU cookie script to pop up a div on androids and drop a cookie once the div is closed. JS alerts are pretty brutal anyway.